# Etching of ZnS crystal by NaOCl

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Can someone tell me the exact mechanism for etching $\ce{ZnS}$ with $\ce{NaOCl}$?
I believe it is due to $\ce{OCl-}$ ion, just need confirmation.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My bet for the active oxidizing agent would be on hypochlorous acid, HOCl, which is in equilibrium with OCl(-) anion in aqueous solution. The sulfide ions on the crystal surface would displace chloride, giving an S-OH(-) species. Additional oxidation at sulfur by HOCl would lead to higher oxidation states of sulfur such as sulfite and sulfate, whose zinc salts are all more water soluble than zinc sulfide. Dissolution of this material from the crystal surface would then result in etching of the crystal.